# PHP function variables

Tags: php, include

I have a function called

```
chewbacca() {
    include('external.php');
    echo $lang[1];
    ...
    }
```

The file external.php contains all the $lang array. However, since I have to execute the function thousands of times, I would like to include only once the file. If I include_once('external.php'); before the function, how can I use the $lang array variables in my function without having to write "global" before each use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless I'm misunderstanding what you're after, you don't need to write `global` before each use, you just have to use it at the start of the function.

```
include('external.php');

chewbacca() {
    global $lang;
    echo $lang[1];
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Maybe passing it as an argument?

```
<?php

include 'external.php';

function chewbacca($lang_array){
    echo $lang_array[1];
    //...
}
```

Edit:

You could do the following too:

On external.php:

```
<?php

return array(
    'foo',
    'foobar',
    'bar',
);
```

On index.php:

```
<?php

function chewbacca($lang_array){
    echo $lang_array[1];
    //...
}

$foo = include 'external.php';
chewbacca($foo);
```

Edit2:
Of course now you can use `include_once`, but I would recommend `require_once` because you won't have the array if the `include` fails and the script should stop with an error.

Comment: Wow i got my certified engineer certificate and i have never seen or used the "$foo = include(file)" before. Does that really work? I thought include was a language construct that returned nothing...

Comment: @Paul Oh well, i just read it, if you "return" something in the included file, it returns it instead of integrating the code into the current location... nice one

Comment: @MathieuDumoulin Of course it works: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.include.php

Answer (score 1):

Simply said, you can't...

You have several ways to do this:

**Way #1**

```
global $lang;
include('external.php')
function chewbacca(){
    global $lang;
    echo $lang[1];
}
```

**Way #2**

```
function chewbacca(){
    include('external.php')
    echo $lang[1];
}
```

**Way #3**

```
function chewbacca(){
    static $lang;
    if(!is_array($lang)){ include('external.php'); }
    echo $lang[1];
}
```

**Way #4**

```
include('external.php')
function chewbacca($lang){
    echo $lang[1];
}
chewbacca($lang);
```

Good luck

PS: Another way would be to use a CLASS a load the strings in the class when it gets created (inside the constructor) and access the language strings from $this->lang...

Answer (score 1):

Static class also is a solution.

```
class AppConfiguration {
    static $languages = array(
      'en' => 'English'  
    );
}

function functionName($param) {
    $lang = AppConfiguration::$languages;
}
```

require_once that class in document and that's it.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood you correctly, try and pass it to a local scope before using it; that way you'll only need to use the global scope once inside the function.